# python selenium get button by class and click

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath

I am using selenium with Python.  The page has a button with a class associated with it.  I used the get element by class, but it fails.  pls check the code below

```
<div class="form-cell">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

have tried the following so far ... and each occassion its the same error.  In the acutal code first three lines are commented, so pls take note.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-orange').click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn btn-orange').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"]/[@class="btn btn-orange"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']/option[text()='Sign Up']").click()
```

This is the same error message for all the above tries.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@type='button']/option[text()='Sign Up']"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

I have managed to identify the text boxes and input certain data into it.  but now am trying to submit that data, but cant seem to get a grip of the button to click it.

thank you for your help

Comment: Can you provide a link to the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-orange').click()
```

`find_element_by_class_name()` does not handle spaces in the class name properly.

If you want to use an XPath, I think it should be like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-orange"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit" and (contains(@class,"btn-orange")) and(contains(text(),"Sign Up"))]').click()
```

this should catch it 100% ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
.//button[@type='submit' and text()='Sign Up']
```

There is no type as 'button' and text as option in the html you shared